# Python packaging - how to make sub-modules importable from higher-level module?

Tags: python, pip, packaging, python-packaging, python-importlib

The following works in my python package:

```
import Top.Lower
```

However, the following does not work:

```
import Top
print(Top.Lower)
```

I'm using `packages = find:` in my setup.cfg as well as:

```
[options.package_data]
Top =
    **/*.py
```

Any idea how to get the `import Top` syntax to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Tell it to import everything from `Top`:**

```
from Top import *  # Asterisk means everything.

print(Top.Lower)  # Should work.
print(Top.OtherLower)  # Should also work.
```

Comment: That's what I ended up doing.